# Undo jQuery or revert DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery that runs on a page. As a short-term fix I want to remove the code within the  tags (containing the JS), that are on the page so that this jQuery does NOT run.

Is there any way that I can do this, or stop the code from running? I want to revert back to the typical DOM state, not the manipulated one...

Edit:

I have a script tag on the page that runs some javascript.

Due to certain limitations, I can't simply remove this - I have to include a javascript file to remove this script tag / OR prevent this javascript from running.

I want to revert back to how the page should look without having been manipulated by the script tag that is already on the page.

Comment: Have you tried disabling JavaScript?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve, are you wanting to stop exceution of javascript, remove dom elements, or undo dom changes.

Comment: **"short-term fix"** of what?

Comment: The code is on the page. I can only affect this via another 'included' javascript file.

Comment: I did some tests with removing `<script>` tag. Didn't work. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/P6JHN/14/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can only include a javascript file, you could try re-declaring the jquery object so it can't run:

```
jQuery = null;
$ = null;
```

That would kill jQuery providing it's loaded *after*. This however would probably cause of lot of javascript errors. On that trail of thought, you could just plug in some broken JS and it would stop jQuery from executing if it's *before* the jQuery stuff.

Comment: Thanks, this would be a great solution but unfortunately I use jQ a lot elsewhere. I was thinking perhaps $("script:eq(5)").remove(); but doesn't seem to work either :(

Comment: Could I define this AFTER by using JS, so write in to the page after the initial jQuery runs?

Comment: Yeah, just try it! As soon as you nullify the variables, it will kill jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code out of the jQuery(document).ready function, that should make the HTML stay the way it was.

After reading your additions in edit, I think the only to see the page before loading that script would be to add a break-point using Firebug script console at that particular script.

Edit: Add further answer after reading the OPs edit.

Comment: Forgot to mention - Place it inside another function instead. (leaving the code out of dom ready function would still run the script).

Answer (score 0):

I can't think on a scenario where it's needed.
And indeed it's impossible to revert the DOM after manipulation. `reset` button doesn't revert the DOM

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret what you are saying but it is not impossible to revert dom changes just 'tricky', [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/P6JHN/12/) is something I have been trying just this week

Comment: @TomIngram. I can't see any 'reset' button there. only a history stack. a code that implements the `command` design patterns (with bugs...)

Comment: this was indeed just a sketch to test the principle and is clearly work in progress, if you want a full reset of the dom why not just refresh `window.location.reload(true);`

Comment: @TomIngram. JQuery code will run once again... that won't solve a thing. **"it's impossible" like I wrote**

Answer (score 0):

if its in a method you can just use `return false;` before your code runs, you can also just comment out your code, or wrap your code in a method that never runs:

```
$("p").hide();
```

becomes:

```
function() {
    $("p").hide();
}
```

Or have I misunderstood your question?

Answer (score 0):

the only way I can think of you achieving this without manipulating the source or dom would be to test for a cookie prior to code execution,if it does not exist then set it and continue executing the rest of your code *something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/73vzD/7/)*. When you want to revert changes made in the dom back to the 'original' just refresh the window and the existence of the cookie will prevent execution a second time

```
(function() {
    if($.cookie('foo') == null) {
        $.cookie('foo', 'bar');
        $('#alert').click(function() {
            alert('run');
        });
    }
})();
```

the only flaw I can see in this is if a user rejects the cookie in which case if it really matters I would alert the user and again break out of execution